# Problem with Data Binding ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have a ViewModel

```
class FontsViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public FontsViewModel()
    {
        InitFonts();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Typeface> Fonts
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    protected void InitFonts()
    {
        Fonts = (ObservableCollection<Typeface>)System.Windows.Media.Fonts.SystemFontFamilies;
    }
}
```

and i bind it in XAML

```
<ribbon:RibbonComboBox.DataContext>
    <vm:FontsViewModel />
</ribbon:RibbonComboBox.DataContext>
<ribbon:RibbonGallery>
    <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory ItemsSource="{Binding Fonts}">
        <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontFamily="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemTemplate>
    </ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory>
</ribbon:RibbonGallery>
```

when i try running, i get

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  Message='The invocation of the constructor on type 'MarkdownEditMVVM.ViewModels.FontsViewModel' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '57' and line position '26'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=57
  LinePosition=26
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
       at MarkdownEditMVVM.MainWindow.InitializeComponent() in d:\Projects\MarkdownEdit\MarkdownEditMVVM\MainWindow.xaml:line 1
       at MarkdownEditMVVM.MainWindow..ctor() in D:\Projects\MarkdownEdit\MarkdownEditMVVM\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 25
  InnerException: System.InvalidCastException
       Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[System.Windows.Media.FontFamily]' to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[System.Windows.Media.Typeface]'.
       Source=MarkdownEditMVVM
       StackTrace:
            at MarkdownEditMVVM.ViewModels.FontsViewModel.InitFonts() in D:\Projects\MarkdownEdit\MarkdownEditMVVM\ViewModels\FontsViewModel.cs:line 26
            at MarkdownEditMVVM.ViewModels.FontsViewModel..ctor() in D:\Projects\MarkdownEdit\MarkdownEditMVVM\ViewModels\FontsViewModel.cs:line 15
       InnerException:
```

what am i doing wrong? its like a modified version of what i see on [Lesters Tutorial on WPF Ribbon](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2010/08/19/using-ribbongallery-control.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot convert a SystemFontFamilies to an ObservableCollection. 
Instead instantiate a new collection:

```
  Fonts = new ObservableCollection<Typeface> (Fonts.SystemFontFamilies);
```

edit: The above code has a mismatch between the property type and the collection type.
Instead use one of the below:

```
        var myFonts = new ObservableCollection<FontFamily>(Fonts.SystemFontFamilies);

        var typefaces = new ObservableCollection<Typeface>(Fonts.SystemTypefaces);
```

Comment: Hmm when i try this, I have renamed `Fonts` to `AvailableFonts` so that it doesn't collide with `System.Windows.Media.Fonts` but i still get errors ... [http://pastebin.com/eZ2PBfFJ](http://pastebin.com/eZ2PBfFJ). Oh and u say i cannot convert `SystemFontFamilies` to `ObservableCollection`, but i did do a cast?

Comment: adding to this, `ObservableCollection` can be casted to `IEnumerable` but `IEnumerable` cannot (always) be casted to `ObservableCollection`. I say *always because not all `IEnumerable`s are `ObservableCollection`s but all `ObservableCollection`s are `IEnumberable`s. hope this clears some of your questions.

Answer (score 4):

Two points:

1. You really don't need an ObservableCollection here (if the list of Fonts will never change.)  It's sufficient to expose an `IEnumerable<Typeface>` property.
2. You really shouldn't be referencing a View-specific object like a Typeface from a ViewModel.  It would be better to expose the available font names as strings and inject the available names through some service interface.  The service interface (on the View side) would then call `System.Windows.Media.Fonts.SystemFontFamilies` and cast to string names.  This gives you isolation for testability (your unit tests can supply their own font names.)

Comment: I don't know if i did it the correct way, but i tried using LINQ to order and select the string (via `toString()`) but i still get error see [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/2Q3nZaXg)

Comment: oh i found out the prev error was because Typeface dont implement IComparable so it can't order the selection. i changed it to `orderby font.toString`

Comment: oh and regarding (2), for colors, i should use ARGB hex value?

Comment: @jiewmeng, possibly; it's unusual for a view model to deal directly with colors and, for this particular case, you might bend the rules.  That's because colors are really a kind of data in the model here.  For the best isolation, you'd probably want to use a View-independent string (such as "#FFFF0000" or "Red"), but I could see an argument for using Color types throughout the Model and ViewModel for clarity.